# Out of local stack in Prolog

Tags: prolog, stack

I right now have the following predicate which keeps giving me: `ERROR: Out of local stack`

```
equality(First,Second,Third,Range):-
    mash(First,Second,Third,Range,X),
    mash(First,Second,Third,4,Y),
    equal(X,Y).

equal(X,Y) :- X == Y.
```

I know that all of the functions work correctly. It is supposed to output either true or false which equal will do for me. When I do it though I get a local stack error.

What am doing wrong?

One example would be:

```
equality([-1.0,-1.0],[[0,-1],[-1,0]],0,5)
```

Comment: It just outputs a list. It works correctly.

Comment: Knowing what `mash/5` does is essential to understanding the behavior of this predicate.

Comment: @mbratch Mash creates a list such as [1,1]. then equal was supposed to compare the output of them both.

Comment: But the details (source code) are important to understanding the problem. `equality/4` and `equal/2` aren't recursive predicates. They're not eating up your stack space. I suspect, then, that `mash/5` is doing it. I know you're saying that `mash/5` works, but perhaps there's an issue in this context. If you show your `mash/5` code, and show what query you entered to cause the stack overflow, it can be figured out.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, if you do this instead:

```
equality(First,Second,Third,Range):-
mash(First,Second,Third,Range,X),
mash(First,Second,Third,4,X).
```

The predicate will only succeed if prolog can unify the 4th parameters to have the same value.. your output parameter, meaning that your call to equal/2 is not needed.

On the main point:

If your second call to mash ever fails for any reason, then the first call to mash will be re-entered from backtracking, and prolog might be getting lost trying out all manner of combinations of whatever you have inside mash/5, which you haven't supplied.

You also haven't supplied the code where you are calling equality/4, because it is possible that unless you are handling a false result correctly, equality/4 is being re-entered after it fails first time around (from backtracking), then prolog is getting lost in one of the mash calls as described above.

You can check this by calling the *trace* predicate before calling equality, to step through the code and see where it is failing.

Edit: it might not be just your handing of a false from equality/4.. if any predicate fails downstream of calling equality/4, then equality/4 will be re-entered from backtracking. If you want to avoid re-entry, you will have to use the cut '!' operator to prevent that.

Comment: I just ran it and It seems like it is just going on forever. I want it to just run once through and check if the two are the same. So maybe the first point you made is correct?

Comment: So try 'trace.', then your main predicate, and step through every line to see what it is doing under the covers. Even better (in swi prolog at least), try trace(mash/5, fail) to see if mash is failing at any point.

Comment: It seems as if Range is being decremented infinite times until it overflows.